# How can i restore 'train_op' using get_tensor_by_name , tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new tensorflow user,

I want to restore `train_op`using `get_tensor_by_name` , But i cannot restore

```
    
 # Define train_op  
 train_op=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost_op, name='train_op')

 # retore train op by name 
 tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('train_op')
```

this is error message

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/seongjungkim/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3532, in _as_graph_element_locked
    return op.outputs[out_n]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/seongjungkim/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/Users/seongjungkim/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/Users/seongjungkim/PycharmProjects/Edu_DL/lesson4/Test/copy_Test_Tf_Simple_Alexnet.py", line 31, in test_alexnet
    train_op = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('train_op:0')
  File "/Users/seongjungkim/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3664, in get_tensor_by_name
    return self.as_graph_element(name, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=False)
  File "/Users/seongjungkim/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3488, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "/Users/seongjungkim/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3537, in _as_graph_element_locked
    len(op.outputs)))
KeyError: "The name 'train_op:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'train_op', exists but only has 0 outputs."
```

Using `tf.get_collections(tf.GraphKeys.TRAIN_OP)[0]` , i can restore `train_op`?

and i already try to use `get_operation_by_name` but it was not working

thank you

Comment: `get_operation_by_name` works for me!

Comment: thanks @rvinas! , it also works too me!

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to update your question, because `get_operation_by_name` works. Shall I write an answer?